# How to come back to flutter app after twitter login page

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a flutter application which uses twitter integration. I am using the package: twitter_login: ^2.1.3

Here, I have provided the necessary callback url in the twitter developer. and for iOS I have provided the twitter kit-consumerkey as the callback url also.

In info.plist I have specified the twitter kit-consumerkey in the urlscheme.

Following is my function when twitter button is clicked:

```
Future<AuthResult> initiatetwitterlogin() async {
    final twitterLogin = TwitterLogin(
      apiKey: 'apikeyhere',
      apiSecretKey: 'seecretkeyhere',
      redirectURI: 'redirecturlhere',
    );
    print('Twitter');
    final authResult = await twitterLogin.login();
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    switch (authResult.status) {
      case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        print('Success');
        print(authResult.user.email);
        // success
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        // cancel
        print('Cancekked by user');
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
        // error
        print(authResult.errorMessage);
        break;
    }
    print('Helllllllo Twitter');
  }
```

What happens is that the twitter login page appears, after providing the email and password it redirects to the screen where it says "Wait. we are redirecting you to the app" but it stays on that page itself, it does not go back to my app.

How to bring it to my app? Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: do you get the print messages from your print statements under switch case?

Comment: no..if I cancel the browser then I get the cancel print message..but not the error or logged in print messages.

Comment: did u get any solution? bcz i'm facing the same issue.